# Statistical models and methods to evaluate and forecast "fine price" increases

Tags: forecasting

I want to evaluate the implications of increasing fine prices. I will have a few different scenarios ranging from business as usual, minor increase, proportional increase, categorical increase, to extreme-increases. Each scenario will have different levels of monetary increase depending on the fine details and subprograms. Also, I'd like to do comparative analysis of implementing a strike base system (x times you get a fine, you're out) versus a cooperative non-extreme user lead system.

Are there any models that predict such increases, especially considering that there is a likelihood of people to eitehr decrease their or increase there frequency of fines after a new system is in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Gary Becker discusses this at length famously in "Crime and Punishment: An Economic Approach".  You can find it at

```
http://www.nber.org/chapters/c3625.pdf
```

and in his Nobel lecture section on crime at

```
http://faculty.smu.edu/millimet/classes/eco4361/readings/quantity%20section/becker.pdf
```

Typically, any model of the level of a fine will be intrinsically married to the probability of detection, as in:

```
http://140.247.200.140/faculty/shavell/pdf/81_Amer_Econ_Rev_618.pdf
```

More recently, Harold Winter wrote a book in 2008 titled The economics of crime: an introduction to rational crime analysis. There is a chapter on setting fines and one can straightforwardly form econometric models from the framework provided

An example of a rather elementary game theoretic approach is here:

```
http://bal.buu.ac.th/bal2010/sites/default/files/Research%20report%202008.07.pdf
```